# How to set an attribute with a blank value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use the following:

```
myElement.setAttribute('data-title', title);
```

where `title` is blank I don't get a blank attribute. I get an attribute with no value.

Is there a way to get the blank attribute using either JavaScript or jQuery? I ask because if I can't then the code I have that references the attribute later is going to become complex to deal with the possibility of there being no value.

Comment: what's the difference between a blank attribute and an attribute with no value

Comment: @SteveC What do you want to do ?

Comment: The problem wasn't what I thought it was. Thanks all. Sorry for wasting your time. I was using attr() to get the attribute back, but on the wrong object. It's always something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setAttribute is native function.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("myId");

myElement.setAttribute('data-title', "")

myElement.getAttribute('data-title'); // you get : ""

myElement.getAttribute('data-test'); // you get : null


if (myElement.getAttribute('data-title') !== "" && myElement.getAttribute('data-title') !== null)
    console.log("not empty");
```

If you want to use jQuery prefere, attr :

```
var $myElement = $("#myId");

$myElement.attr("data-title", "");

$myElement.attr("data-title"); // you get : ""

$myElement.attr("data-test"); // you get : undefined

if (myElement.getAttribute('data-title') !== "" && typeof(myElement.getAttribute('data-title')) !== "undefined")
    console.log("not empty");
```

Comment: Thanks. You're entirely correct, but that's not how it seemed to me (see above).

Answer (score 1):

You should use attr

like:

```
myElement.attr('data-ttitle','')
```

to retrieve:

```
var data = myElement.attr('data-ttitle')
```

reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned that I tried that. Same result.

Comment: you will retrieve like empty string when the attribute is blank or undefined when there is no attribute. @SteveC